# Multiple sockets created when accepting connection, but data is treated as if it had been sent by the first connected client

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working on a multiuser chat-like project that is supposed to handle connections from many clients at the same time. When a client connects, I `accept()` the connection and pass it to a `Client` class on its own thread that handles incoming data with a `self.socket.recv(1024)` loop. When data comes in, it is stored in a list called `data-queue`. Then I store this client in a list of `Clients`.

Once every 100ms, I iterate over every `Client` on my `Clients` list and check if the `data-queue` list is empty. If it is not, I print whatever I get by `pop()`-ing the list, and the client address.

The thing is, if many clients connect at the same time, only the first connected `Client` gets all data sent by them as if it was sent by him.

If Client A sends "Hi!" and Client B sends "Hi there!", the server just reads that as if Client A had been the one who send both "Hi!" and "Hi there!" and Client B had stood silent the whole time. If Client A disconnects, all input from further Clients is treated as if it had been sent by the first-remaining Client (in this case Client B, as Client A has left), and so on.

What could it be?

**Edit**:

The source code goes somewhat like this:

```
CLIENTS = []

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('', 1515))
    s.listen(5)
    runCycle()
    while True:
        CLIENTS.append(client(s.accept()))
        CLIENTS[len(CLIENTS)-1].start()

class client(threading.Thread):
    dataQueue = []

    def __init__(self, (socket, address)):
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.data = ""
        while True:
            self.data = self.socket.recv(1024)
            if not self.data:
                break
            dataQueue.append(self.address + " " + self.data)
            self.data = ""

def runCycle():
    threading.Timer(0.1, runCycle).start()
    for c in CLIENTS:
        if len(c.dataQueue) > 0:
            print c.dataQueue.pop()

main()
```

Comment: Too few information,can you post Client's code, please

Comment: There! Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class client(threading.Thread):
    dataQueue = []
```

This means `dataQueue` is static and the same instance of `[]` is shared across threads. Iterating over clients is fruitless in this case, you can just read it from any client object:

```
>>> class C(object):
...   a = []
... 
>>> c1, c2 = C(), C()
>>> c1.a.append(1)
>>> c2.a
[1]
```

Move `dataQueue` into `__init__` to fix this.

```
class client(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, (socket, address)):
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address
        self.dataQueue = []
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
```

And please look into guarding `self.dataQueue` with [a lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects). Odds are lists aren't thread safe.

Comment: Oh! I thought variables declared within the class worked like private C++ class variables. Today I learn. You saved me, thank you very much!